# Is it correct my ajax call and jQuery PHP for submit button only?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

I'm using Kendo grid that has treeview with checkboxes. So, here I want to do POST using AJAX call to get the id of selected checkboxes. Is there any correction on this code? Because there is no function for submit button.

> AJAX call for submit button

```
$("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getTest.php",
            //data: { name: "John" }
            data: function () {
                        return {
                            method: "getTemplate",
                        //  employeeID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['employeeID'];?>",    
                        //  propertyID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['propertyID'];?>",
                        }
                    },
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
    }); 
}
```

> jQuery PHP

```
function getTemplate() {
global $ehorsObj;
$positionTemplateID = (isset($_POST['positionTemplateID']) ? $_POST['positionTemplateID'] : '');
$hrsPositionID      = (isset($_POST['hrsPositionID']) ? $_POST['hrsPositionID'] : '');
$programID          = (isset($_POST['programID']) ? $_POST['programID'] : '');
$propertyID         = (isset($_POST['propertyID']) ? $_POST['propertyID'] : '');
$employeeID         = (isset($_POST['employeeID']));
```

If they are using : If isset $_POST ,
I'm a little bit confused here. Is there any solution on this?

[Demo Here](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY/6)

Comment: Im sorry, but the problem is unclear, please, edit and explain it better.

Comment: I mean here is how do I call a PHP function on click of a button. Because i'm stuck for PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Your demo link has `checkedNodeIds` function. This function holds checked nodes in a multidimensional array like

```
nodes[i].moduleID
nodes[i].groupID
nodes[i].programID
```

So return this array from this function and pass it as ajax data. Then process it in your PHP back-end.

```
function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
          //checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].moduleID);
         // checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].groupID);
          checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].programID);
        }

        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
          checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
        }
      }
    }
```